# How to add multiple url schemes in Expo App without ejecting?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, deep-linking

I am going through [this link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/#handling-links-into-your-app) to add deeplink to my Expo App but could not find any document to add multiple schemes. Is it even possible to add multiple schemes in Expo App without ejecting it?

Comment: What do you mean by “without ejecting it”? Can you please explain the experience you are expecting.

Comment: @Casey looks like they have updated the docs after this question was asked. Are you referring to same?

Comment: I’m asking for clarification as to what you want to achieve. I don’t understand what you mean by “without ejecting it”. In the solution added by AtulParmar you again repeat that “this requires ejecting the expo app”. What does ejecting mean?

Comment: @Casey may be [this reference](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/) can help

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, not familiar with Expo

Answer (score 3):

You can associate multiple URLs to your Expo app without ejecting by configuring the `app.json` file.

For iOS, you will need to modify the [associatedDomains](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#associateddomains) key:

```
{
    ...
    "ios": {
        ...
        "associatedDomains": ["applinks:mydomain.com", "applinks:myotherdomain.com"]
    }
}
```

For Android, you will need to modify the [intentFilters](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#intentfilters) key:

```
{
    ...
    "android": {
        ...
        "intentFilters": [{
            "action": "VIEW",
            "autoVerify": true || false,
            "data": [
                { "scheme": "https", "host": "mydomain.com" },
                { "scheme": "https", "host": "myother.com" }
            ]
            "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
        }]
    }
```

Furthermore, depending on your requirements you might need to verify ownership of the domains you want to associate with your app. Both iOS and Android have different (but similar) ways to achieve this. You can find detailed info about the process in [Expo's deep linking documentation](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/linking/#universaldeep-links-without-a-custom-scheme).

Comment: Do we even get Android and iOS folders without ejecting? Not sure how expo works currently. But at least 2 years ago your solution wouldn't work.

Comment: @MohammedAtif the `app.json` file is located in the root of your Expo project when you select the managed workflow (non-ejected). No need to eject and configure the files in the Android and iOS folders.

Comment: That's good. At least now they support it. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of strings instead of just a string in the `scheme` config property of expo. The documentation has a [bug](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/25516) and doesn't explain this. I wrote a [post](https://www.iliascreates.com/blog/post/multiple-schemes-expo/) about it.

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": ["myapp1", "myapp2"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For IOS application you can add multiple URL schemes using the following steps.

Add URL scheme in info.plist file by adding the following code. (click on info.plist file right click and open as source code.)

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>one</string>
            <string>two</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

[image]

Comment: But this requires ejecting the expo app.